# Multiplying, smallest number and the position of that smallest number

Tags: java

I have an assignment and I've already written the first two parts, I just cant figure out how to do the finding of the smallest number. I should mention that it is in jFrame  (gui). It's supposed to look like this:

[image]

Lets say i have a list of numbers (10 5 8 7 4 9) and I wanna know at which position is the number 7. How do I do that? I've been stuck on this for the last hour. :/
here's what I have so far:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String s = jTextField1.getText();
    String[]divide = s.split(" ");
    int[] number = new int[10];
    int sum = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        number[i] = Integer.parseInt(divide[i]);
        sum = sum * number[i];
    }
    jTextField2.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   String s = jTextField1.getText();
    String[]divide = s.split(" ");
    Arrays.sort(divide);
    jTextField3.setText(divide[0]);
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


    public static int findMin(ArrayList<Integer> n)
{
int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
int minIndex = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < n.size(); i++){
    if(n.get(i) < minValue){
        minIndex = i;
    }
}
return minIndex;
```

Comment: At the risk of offending even more people, you seriously need to learn how to use StackOverflow's built in image uploading or pick a different image hosting service

Comment: Your `findMin` method is almost right.  Just add another statement into your `if` block:  `minvalue = n.get(i);`

Comment: @JasonSperske I already edited the post :)

Comment: Are you sure you need the position of the smallest number? Seems from the image that you need the position of an arbitrary second number supplied by the user.

Answer (score 3):

When you find the index of the minimum value, you should update the `minValue`.

```
public static int findMin(ArrayList<Integer> n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n.size(); i++){
        if(n.get(i) < minValue){
            minIndex = i;
            minValue = n.get(i);   //Update here
        }
    }
    return minIndex;
}
```

Your code is always comparing the *i-th* element with `int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;` that you never change.

Adding it below the `if` statement will update it, and you'll get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for answers and I'm sorry about the image file hosting.
But I ran across one more problem, on the public static int findMin(ArrayList<Integer> n)  it says illegal start of expression. How to work around this?

Comment: You probably have unbalanced brackets, or declaring a method inside a method.

Comment: so I cant declare the public static int findMin(ArrayList<Integer> n) in the last button? because I checked all the brackets and their fine :/

Comment: I'm sorry I have  so many questions, i know it might seem annoying and stupid of me, but how do set it to the jTextField4 i have created for it?

Comment: The same way you did for the others. You shouldn't have this method inside the `jButton3ActionPerformed`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. So how do I do it without the method? :/

Comment: You can move the method to outside the `ActionPerformed` body, and inside it you only set the `JTextField4`. (e.g. `jTextField4.setText(findMin(....));`) But I don't know where this `ArrayList` comes from, you should take care of it.

Comment: Okay so I found a similar question asked and I altered it a bit, but in int[] a = jTextField5... it won't accept it.
   `int[] a = jTextField5.getText();
    int small = a[0];
    int smallest = a[0];
    for(int i:a){
        if(i<smallest)
            smallest=i;
    }
    for(int i:a){
        if(i<small&&i!=smallest)
            small=i;
    }
    jTextField4.setText(Integer.toString(small));
`